# Regular Expression for Alphabets + Numeric Value

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am working on a Java-script, for which I need regular expression to check whether the entered text in text-box should be combination of alphabets and numeric value.

I tried NaN function of java-script but string should be of minimum-size & maximum-size of length 4 and start with Alphabet as first element and remaining 3 element should be numbers.

For example : Regular expression for A123, D456, a564 and not for ( AS23, 1234, HJI1 )

Please suggest me !!!

Code Here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var textcode = document.form1.code.value;
  function fourdigitcheck(){
    var textcode = document.form1.code.value;
    alert("textcode:"+textcode);
    var vmatch = /^[a-zA-Z]\d{3}$/.test("textcode");
    alert("match:"+vmatch);
    }
</script>
<form name="form1">
 Enter your Number  <input type="text" name="code" id="code"   onblur="fourdigitcheck()" />
</form>
```

Comment: **Javascript** specific: http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml

Comment: after your modification, the line 6:     var vmatch = /^[a-zA-Z]\d{3}$/.test("textcode");

has to be changed:     var vmatch = /^[a-zA-Z]\d{3}$/.test(textcode);

Comment: change: var vmatch = /^[a-zA-Z]\d{3}$/.test("textcode");
to: var vmatch = /^[a-zA-Z]\d{3}$/.test(textcode);
and it will work fine. see: http://jsfiddle.net/E2Kfr/

Comment: @Rubber : Thanks Dear, It really works !!!
@Floyddotnet : Awesome Dude, your script is really nice one ....Thanks a lot for giving me such a nice idea !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" name="form" action="#">
  <input type="text" onkeyup=
   "document.getElementById('s').innerHTML=this.value.match(/^[a-z]\d\d\d$/i)?'Good':'Fail'" 
   />
  <span id="s">?</span>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
^[A-Z]{1}\d{3}$
```

or shorter

```
^[A-Z]\d{3}$
```

Description:

```
// ^[A-Z]\d{3}$
// 
// Assert position at the start of the string or after a line break character «^»
// Match a single character in the range between "A" and "Z" «[A-Z]»
// Match a single digit 0..9 «\d{3}»
//    Exactly 3 times «{3}»
// Assert position at the end of the string or before a line break character «$»
```

Test:

```
/*
A123 -> true
D456 -> true
AS23 -> false
1234 -> false
HJI1 -> false
AB456 -> false
*/
```

Comment: he doesn't say anything about first letter being capital (though all examples do): `/^[a-z]\d{3}$/i`

Comment: @Rahul _dear_, the regex is correct - post the code that you're using to test it.

Comment: @Amaraghosh: he doesn't say that not. all exampels he post are capital.

Answer (score 3):

[This website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) will tell you exactly what you need to know.

Answer (score 3):

Regexp:

```
var match = /^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}$/.test("A456"); // match is true
var match = /^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}$/.test("AB456"); // match is false
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html - there's an online testing tool where you can check if it works all right.

Answer (score 1):

/[A-Z][0-9]{3}/

Answer (score 1):

If you want both upper and lower case letters then   `/^[A-Za-z][0-9]{3}$/`

else if letters are upper case then    `/^[A-Z][0-9]{3}$/`